# Using custom lasso to select any UIElement?

Tags: .net, wpf, uielement

We are trying to implement the same Lasso behavior of `InkCanvas` with `Canvas` to select any `UIElement`. We tried using (IncrementalLassoHitTester) mentioned in this 
[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms788721%28v=vs.90%29), but it wasn't helpful because it selects strokes only.

Is there any way to achieve this goal?